# Can I access the filesystem of an android device?

Tags: file-system

I have an android device that doesn't start because it tries to activate carrier's network.
Its out-of-contact CDMA mobile which was ported to another carrier.
I accidentally did a reset and after that it always tried to activate carrier.

Currently when I connect it, I can see it as MTP Device, but I don't see the filesystem.
Is it possible for me to go to the filesystem directly and remove possible apk files that cause this?

I am thinking of chroot-ing or something similar into the system and remove all the stuff that could trigger this activation.
Do I need to use ADB shell or to connect to the device?

Comment: You'll need root permissions to modify the file system.  Once you get that, you'll be able to do anything you want.

Comment: Rooting the OS while the device does not boot up seems tricky, however ;-)

Answer (score 2):

To get access to the filesystem you need to be rooted and you need to use ADB. MTP is way to limited for the low level access your needing.